# What are paraid and paraeid when pasting from Microsoft Word Online?

Tags: jquery, ckeditor, office365, clipboard, copy-paste

I'm trying to create a plug-in for CKEditor that will preserve formatting when pasting from Microsoft Word Online. I created this basic paste to check how Microsoft Word Online stores data in the clipboard.

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.add('superpaste',
    {
        requires: [],
        init: function (editor) {
            editor.on('paste', function (evt) {
                alert('pasting: ' + evt.data.dataValue);
            })
        }
    }
);
```

This is the block of text I'm using to test.

Regular **Bold** *Italic* Underline <s>Strikethrough</s> <sup>Superscript</sup><sub>substript</sub> ***BoldItalic*** <s>UnderlineStrikethrough</s>
Note: underline doesn't appear to work in stackoverflow.
When pasting from almost any source, including the Microsoft Word desktop application, the formatting gets transferred correctly into the CKEditor.
When pasting from Microsoft Word Online, I do not see any styles. Instead I see "paraid" and "paraeid" attributes of "p" tags.
What are these paraid and paraeid? Do they contain format data, or is that somewhere else? Is there documentation somewhere for how to copy/paste from Microsoft Word Online?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CKEditor dev here.

The HTML pasted form MS Word Online contains inline styles, which would normally be represented as tags (e.g. `style: bold` and the `<strong>` tag), so (in Chrome/Safari) they get filtered out by the paste filter.

Of course you can always disable this, more info here:
http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-pasteFilter